# Symfony2 create a service

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection

There used to be a how-to in the symfony2 doc on how to create a service (my_mailer) but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Can anyone tell me where to find it, or some other tutorial on how to create a service in symfony2 ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Service Container - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Creating/Configuring Services in the Container - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container

Great example of a service - a Twig Extension - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: This information is good, but it's more about how to think in service way, not how to really define a service in symfony. Like right syntax en good practise. It is the right answer though. I figured it out with trial and error.