# Call to a member function get() on null while creating form

Tags: php, symfony

I want to call method inside class that creates form. But I get this error.

```
Error: Call to a member function get() on null
```

This is class that should handle form operations.

```
class CommentController extends Controller 
{
    public function replyAction()
    {
        $comment = new Comments();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($comment)
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('text', TextType::class)
        ->add('reply', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Reply'))
        ->getForm();

        return $this->$form;
    }
}
```

and this is how i Call the method from another class

```
$form = (new CommentController())->replyAction();
```

It works if I place the `replyAction` code into class that I am calling it from, but I want to have it inside separate class.

Comment: Not really related to you problem I guess, but just getting sure of it... Your formBuilder is in your controller, right? If so, why?

Comment: Try to define your controller as service if you want to call it from an another class, like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366074/how-exactly-can-i-define-a-controller-as-service-using-annotations

Comment: Make a formType class: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Comment: Remove dollar "$" from $this->$form in your controller.

Comment: I just moved the method to the class that i want to use it in for now. But that formType class looks like it could do what I wanted.

Comment: Besides the formType class you could create a custom class that handles the creation, validation and actions that need to be done. You can also add your custom class to the service container http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085376/symfony2-create-a-service

Answer (score 1):

To answer your actual question, the reason you are getting the error is because something called the container is not being injected into your controller.  In theory you could fix this with something like:

```
// SomeOtherClass
$commentController = new CommentController();
$commentController->setContainer($container);
$form = $commentController->replyAction(); // Assuming replyAction has 'return $form;'
```

Needless to say, your SomeOtherClass may or may not have access to the container.

The real question of course is why you are trying to do such a thing?  Because quite frankly, it does not make much sense.  It is not uncommon for developers to mix up controllers with services and what not.

Consider updating your question with an explanation of what you trying to do.  Create a form via a service perhaps?